# Successor of Codehaus Modello?

Tags: java, apache, maven

Out of curiousity, Apache Maven builds on [Modello](https://github.com/codehaus/modello) for Code-generation (Pojos, Marshallers etc.).

There is even now a [Modello Editor](https://github.com/takari/modello-editor) in development.

But, Modello has no commits for 5 years now.

Who is the new kid on the block for model generators? Not speaking of heavyweights like Avro..

Answer (score 1):

CodeHaus is no more (officially closed down), but I believe there is still some Modello development going on here:
https://github.com/sonatype/modello

There was some talk (incidentally, 5 years ago) about merging Modello into EMF (https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/), but I am not sure whether anything came out of it in the end.